# How to show ajax loading gif only for a specific request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, request, gif

How do you show ajax gif only for a specific request?
For example my page is calling a web-service every 30 seconds in a background, and I don't want to show the gif during this callback. On the other hand I want to show the gif, when I'am making manual ajax requests.

I am using jQuery.

*edit: I didn't setup the global handler as shown here http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/, just by attaching to the .ajaxStart event. But I don't want to show/hide the gif manually on every request too. I need some generic solution.*

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information?  Where in your jQuery are you setting this loading animation?  A snippet or two of code would be extremely useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#manualRefresh').click(function(){
    $('#myContainer').html('<img src="my-ajax-gif.gif">');
    $.get( ..., function(data){ ('#myContainer').html(data) });
});
```

Like that?

Comment: thank you, Ben, but please see my edited question. 
I need some general solution, don't want duplicate the show/hide code on every request.

Comment: What about taking the anonymous function provided by Ben and wrapping it in a function (or plugin, if you need this in many places) that both shows your gif and submits your request?

Comment: you are right, KISS as it is.
thank you, Ben, thank you, justkt.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
$('#save').click(function(){
    $('#ShowLoading').show();
    $.ajax( ..., success:function(data){....$('#ShowLoading').hide();}, 
          error:function(){....$('#ShowLoading').hide();});
});
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I use the [BlockUI plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/), makes it pretty easy really. This is a simple wrapper function I wrote for some demo code:

```
function wjBlockUI(msg) {

var defaultMsg = '<img src="../images/activity.gif" />';

if (null !== msg) {
    defaultMsg = msg
}

$.blockUI({ overlayCSS: { backgroundColor: '#aaa' }, message: defaultMsg });
```

}